# Is it possible to map permissions to HTTP methods in Keycloak integrated with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

It seems to me that with Keycloak you can do the authorisation in many different ways. However, I still try to get my head around how all these works.

We have hundreds of APIs and they are all bound to GET, DELETE, PATCH and POST. So far I found that in order to map these HTTP methods, is to add them as `scope`.

So assume we have an API with this URI: `/api/investor/{id}`. This can be `GET`, `DELETE` or `PATCH`. Now this is how it is said we should configure it (for simplicity I just try to show them with `linked` as in they are assigned in Keyclaok configuration, so please ignore the direction as it may not be the same as the actual direction in Keycloak class diagram):

```
user-one =linked=> call-centre-read-only-role =linked=> read-only-policy =linked=> 
    view-permission =linked=> investor-resource-read(/api/investor/{id}) =linked=> scope(GET)
```

Now we need another `Resource` definition for those with read and write access

```
user-two =linked=> admin-read-write-role =linked=> readwrite-policy =linked=> 
    write-permission =linked=> investor-resource-write(/api/investor/{id}) =linked=> scope(GET,DELETE,PATCH)
```

As you can see the same resource (with the same URI) are being duplicated and that's because from our point of view the permissions are defined in `scope` as HTTP methods.

Given we have many APIs this seems to be very complicated and hard to configure. However, I was thinking it would be much nicer if we had to define it this way:

```
user-one =linked=> call-centre-read-only-role =linked=> read-only-policy =linked=> 
    read-permission:scope(GET) =linked=> investor-resource(/api/investor/{id})
```

and for admins:

```
user-two =linked=> admin-read-write-role =linked=> readwrite-policy =linked=> 
    update-permission:scope(PATCH) =linked=> investor-resource(/api/investor/{id}) 

user-two =linked=> admin-read-write-role =linked=> readwrite-policy =linked=> 
    delete-permission:scope(DELETE) =linked=> investor-resource(/api/investor/{id})
```

This way we can re-user the same `Resource` definition for multiple permissions. Now the question is whether with this configuration, Keycloak adapter can identify the HTTP method and authorise the user based on that. If not, how else can we do that to be able to reuse the `Resource`s?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Keycloak adapter can do this out of the box. You may want to check the [documentation on policy enforcers](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_enforcer_filter).

With this you can map your http methods to a scope by configuration like this:

```json
{
  "policy-enforcer": {
    ...
    "paths": [
      {
        "name" : "Investor resource",
        "path" : "/api/investor/{id}",
        "methods" : [
          {
            "method": "GET",
            "scopes" : ["urn:my.custom.app:scopes:view"]
          },
          {
            "method": "PUT",
            "scopes" : ["urn:my.custom.app:scopes:view", "urn:my.custom.app:update"]
          },
          {
            "method": "DELETE",
            "scopes" : ["urn:my.custom.app:scopes:remove"]
          }
        ]
      },
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Well it does it against the `Resource` and it ignores it when we have Scope-based permissions. If we have a scope-based permission that mapped to say `GET` but the resource mapped to `GET` and `DELETE`, it doesn't return `DENIED` for `DELETE` request because your resource has the both scopes for get/delete